# Auto create a record for history of object when persist it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, data-annotations

I'm looking for an approach to auto-generate a record everytime a class I have is persisted to the data base, without triggers or database functions.

My classe Item is something like that

```
/// <summary>
/// Modelo de representação do Item (Produto) 
/// </summary>
[Table("Item")]
public class Item : History
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id único gerador pelo sistema
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Nome do produto
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Código de barras
    /// </summary>
    public string BarCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Código da imagem do produto na base de dados
    /// </summary>
    public long Image_Id { get; set; }
}
```

My repository class of Item has an insert to persist it. Like that

```
 /// <summary>
/// Repositório do objeto Item
/// </summary>
public class ItemRepository : BaseRepository<Item>
{
    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Inicializa o repositório de Item 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Contexto usado em sua inicialização</param>
    public ItemRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public override void Insert(Item entity)
    {
        base.Insert(entity);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My question is: How can I generate a record to my objetc Item__History which represents a mirror for my item object in this momento? Everytime I update this objetct Item, I need the method of my repository (update) to generate another insert into Item__History, creating another object that reflects this exact moment of Item.

Later, I can go Item__History and check all the states this class Item already have.

I can do It by creating a model for Item__History (ok, it's created) and creating a repository class to Item__History, and during the insert/update of Item inside the repository class, I create an instance of Item__History, copy all the values into this new instance and call the Item__Repository to insert it to. I'm not sure if it's the best approach, since I'll have a lot of classes which I want to manager the history, and don't want to have a lot of "XXX___History" classes and repositories.

Sorry, btw if the question isn't good enough. I hope someone understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about if You create `GenericHistoryRepository` class with `IGenericHistoryRepository` interface and implement methods`Add()`,`AddList()`,`Update()` and `Remove()`. Such a generic class you will be able to take advantage of its various entities. You can follow this code.

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.DataAccessObject
{
    public interface IGenericHistoryRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        void Add(params T[] items);
        void AddList(params T[] items);
        void Update(params T[] items);
        void Remove(params T[] items);

    }
    public class GenericHistoryRepository<T> : IGenericHistoryRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        public virtual void Add(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new MainContext())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        public void AddList(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new MainContext())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new MainContext())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        public virtual void Remove(params T[] items)
        {
            using (var context = new MainContext())
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }

 }
```

Usage

```
   public override void Insert(Item entity)
    {
        base.Insert(entity);
        new GenericHistoryRepository<Item_History>().Add(entity);
    }
    ...

    new GenericHistoryRepository<XXX_History>().Add(entity);
```

Comment: Looks good but the entity on the second code sample you post, is an Item. When you call the new GenericHistoryRepository<Item_History>().Add(entity) you send an Item instead Item__History model. They have a  little difference between both (maybe I'm doing it wrong). The __History class has an  XXXX_Id (like Item_Id) which references to the property Id of Item (to know which item this history is for). Am I right asking that?

Comment: Are you use single entitie as history for all others entities? _"I'll have a lot of classes which I want to manager the history, and don't want to have a lot of "XXX___History" classes and repositories."_ I mean each entitie XXX have XXX_History. In this case generic history repository is good move in earlier case You need to create own logic where you check which exactly id of item is it. But this logic should not be integrated with repositories. Can be add to business logic

Comment: Also in insert method you can create new Item_history and send instead entity. But i dont know is it good idea adding this logic to repositories.

Comment: hmmm ok I guess I got what you mean :) thanks a lot for your time!